# JS/AngularJS: Dynamically create variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to declare variable with name based on the same root but with different names as in the below example:

```
$scope.form1 = //something
$scope.form2 = //something
```

the scope is to create dynamically this name using another variable. Something like this:

```
$scope.form[count] = //something
```

but the result should be something like form1 and not form.1

thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a string with the full name of the property.

```
$scope["form" + count]
```

… although a better approach would probably be to not have property names that differ only by a number in a first place. Use one property with an array as its value instead.

```
$scope.forms = [something, something];
$scope.forms[count];
```